# Select all characters of a list that have given substrings

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe where the colunm names have a structure as follows:

```
Barcelona.Standard.2012.True
Berlin.One.2013.True
London.One.2014.True
Barcelona.Standard.2015.True
Berlin.One.2016.True
```

As you can see, each column specifies the `City`, `Type of bank account`, `Year it was open` and if it's `Active` or not.

Something like:

```
col <- c("Barcelona.Standard.2012.True",
         "Berlin.One.2013.True",
         "London.One.2014.True",
         "Barcelona.Standard.2015.True",
         "Berlin.One.2016.True")
```

This is a toy dataset, and of course the real data has a lot more columns.

I would like a way of printing all the columns that have a given combination of strings.

So for example, for the values:

```
Barcelona
Standard
True
```

We would get a list with the next two values:

```
[1] Barcelona.Standard.2012.True
[2] Barcelona.Standard.2015.True,
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grep` with a regex i.e. if the order of occurrence of the words are `Barcelona`, followed by `Standard` and then `True`, the `.*` between those words will fill for the characters that can be present between them

```
grep("Barcelona.*Standard.*True", col, value = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "Barcelona.Standard.2012.True" "Barcelona.Standard.2015.True"
```

---

If they occur in any order, an option is also to extract the substring with `gregexpr` and check for the `lengths` to create a logical expression

```
col[lengths(gregexpr('Barcelona|Standard|True', col)) == 3]
[1] "Barcelona.Standard.2012.True" "Barcelona.Standard.2015.True"
```